# Как правильно сделать проверку формы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, валидация

Как правильно отследить валидацию формы?

Вот мой код:

```html
<form class="form__action" action="">
  <div class="form__user-name">
    <label class="form__label">Ваше имя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form__input js-type-user" />
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-mail">
    <label class="form__label">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form__input js-type-email" />
  </div>
  <div class="form__user-password">
    <label class="form__label">Придумайте пароль:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form__input js-type-pass" />
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form__check" checked/>
  <label class="form__text">Регистрируясь, вы подтверждаете, что вам уже исполнилось <br/>
                        18 лет и вы ознакомились с условиями пользования сайтом.
                    </label>
  <div class="page__transition page__transition-blue">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-blue btn-blue-disabled">продолжить</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

У меня есть проверка на каждый `<input>` сделанная через JavaScript.
Как сделать, что бы когда все `<input>` прошли валидацию?
Убрать класс с кнопки `btn-blue-disabled`, что бы кнопка сразу среагировала, когда верно заполнены `<input>`?

Разобрались с кнопкой, теперь возникла другая проблема, вот мой код валидации `<input>` на имя:

```
var userName = document.querySelector(".js-type-user");
    var letterOnly = /^([a-zа-яё]+|)$/i;
    userName.onchange = function () {
        if (letterOnly.test(this.value)) {
            isValidateUser = true;
        }
    };
```

Проблема в следующем: меняется `isValidateUser` на `true` и все работает, но когда я даже стираю в `<input>` все буквы, `isValidateUser` все равно остается `true`, пробовал добавить:

```
if(this.value == ""){
            isValidateUser = false;
        }
```

Но безрезультатно. В чем может крыться проблема?

Comment: вашу проверку напишите в вопросе

Comment: К первому if допишите else и поставьте значение переменной false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так. Но советую все-таки полагаться ТОЛЬКО на серверную валидацию через аякс, ибо манипулировать с браузером очень просто.

Общий принцип простой: у вас есть "глобальная" переменная, которая меняется в зависимости от валидаций ваших инпутов. И если изначально эта переменная была true (то есть позволяла отправить форму - или наоборот, как удобно), то если в каком-то инпуте валидация не пройдет, эта переменная поменяется на false. Далее делаем проверку на переменную после нескольких ивентов с формой. НО я бы не назвал этот способ классным, потому что он грузит браузер пользователя.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isFormValid = true;

    function validateForm() {
        // в этой части все ваши валидации инпутов. Если инпут валидацию не проходит, ставите isFormValid = false;

        // пример валидация email
        if(!/(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)/.test($('#email').val())) isFormValid = false;
    }
    // в принципе эта функция validateForm не нужна, тут она присутствует для примера. Менять переменную isFormValid вы можете в ваших валидациях

    $('.form__action').on('change focus blur keydown keyup mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        // на практически любом взаимодействии с формой проверяем валидность
        validateForm();
        if (isFormValid == true) {
            $('.btn').removeClass('btn-blue-disabled');
        } else {
            $('.btn').addClass('btn-blue-disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, понял в каком направлении двигаться! У меня еще один маленький вопрос по поводу валидации через сервер. Как его правильно организовать? Можно вот эти переменные isFormValid поместить в какой-то JSON файлик и оттуда проверять? Извините, если вопрос глупый, просто не совсем в этом разбираюсь. Спасибо!